# NgbModal error when trying to close

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I've successfully imtegrated the NgbModal into my Angular 2 application, I currently have another component being shown within the modal.

The issue I have is once it's appeared and I click close I get the following error message:

```
Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

Now I've been following [Components as content](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) I've looked at the HTML and also gone through the Typescript, however I'm unsure what I'm actually missing here.

This is my type script file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BugService } from '../service/bug.service';
import { Bug } from '../model/bug';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BugDetailComponent } from '../../bug-detail/bug-detail.component';

@Component({
   selector: 'bug-list',
   templateUrl: './bug-list.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./bug-list.component.css']
})

export class BugListComponent implements OnInit {

  private bugs: Bug[] = [];

  constructor(private bugService: BugService, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAddedBugs();
  }

  getAddedBugs() {
    this.bugService.getAddedBugs().subscribe(bug => {
        this.bugs.push(bug);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    },
        err => {
            console.error("unable to get added bug - ", err);
        });
  }

  open() {
     const modalRef = this.modalService.open(BugDetailComponent);
     modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```

I import `BugDetailComponent` which I then reference inside the `open()` function.  When I click close after the modal has appeared that's when I see the error message.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="modal-header" [id]="modalId">
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

Could someone please shed some light into why I receive this error and maybe help me fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ignore, I fixed this.  Was missing the following constructor off the `bug-detail.component.ts`

```
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
```

Comment: I am getting an error : `Error: No provider for NgbActiveModal!` Any help??

Comment: add NgbActiveModal  to providers in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having the same issue (i tried the solution by Code Ratchet, but ran into the same issue as Adrita Sharma).

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(BugDetailComponent);
```

I was able to use `close` and `dismiss` by using modalRef.close() in the template.

example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="modalRef.close('Close click')">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add in your file app.module.ts : the
providers: [ NgbActiveModal ],

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Better You give a method and close it in your .ts page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
```

and in your .ts file

```
 closeModal(){this.modalService.dismissAll();}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add NgbActiveModal in providers[NgbActiveModal] of your module.it will avaiable in all your component of your module then declare its variable in constructor function of your componet like constructor(private ngvActiveModal: NgbActiveModal);

Answer (score -2):

You can run into same error in case import "NgbModal" is missing in line

`import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

Comment: This is just untrue